# Why does this work? JNDI, Tomcat6

Tags: java, jdbc, tomcat6, jndi

I am trying to move all the database information out of the projects so the SA can setup the servers and move the same WAR from DEV->QA->PROD without changing anything in the WAR files. We setup JNDI to a MySQL database on tomcat6.

Add the following to the server.xml

```
<Resource name="jdbc/mi" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              username="xxx" password="xxx"
              url="jdbc:mysql://xx"
              driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
              initialSize="5" maxWait="5000"
              maxActive="120" maxIdle="5"
              validationQuery="select 1"
              poolPreparedStatements="true"/>
```

But the project does not work right.  I get the following error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'
```

if I setupp a /META-INF/context.xml with the same information in my project everything runs great but the SA does not want the server information in my war.  what can it be??  can someone please help me out on this one.. I search all over the internet and was trying everything but nothing works.. please help a programmer out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you setup `WEB-INF/web.xml` in your project? It should contain something like this

```
<resource-env-ref>
    <resource-env-ref-name>jdbc/mi</resource-env-ref-name>
    <resource-env-ref-type>javax.sql.DataSource</resource-env-ref-type>
</resource-env-ref>
```

You didn't mention it in your question, so it may be missing. See this [Java documentation](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2EE/injection/)
and [the Tomcat6' one](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html)

Answer (score 1):

In your context.xml, you need a resource link so that the app knows to look globally for the resource.

```
<ResourceLink name="jdbc/mi" global="jdbc/mi"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the above answers, you'll need to make sure the JDBC library for your DB is placed in the ${TOMCAT_HOME}/lib folder.